# Website Template Like (As) Math StackExchange for Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, latex

I recently had [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294439/definitions-of-lyapunov-exponent-and-chaos-for-flows-of-vector-fields-note-to) deleted in Math StackExchange. I was mainly using it as a "note to self" in LaTeX, but answers would have been nice.

Is there a webpage I can install on my Ubuntu Linux Apache2 webserver that will be exactly like (as close as possible to) the Math StackExchange website so I can record "notes to myself" on it and not worry about "offending" the Math StackExchange crowd? This would be super-helpful to me, and the Math StackExchange people would appear to like it as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not being able to see your deleted question, I wonder what particular _feature_ of the web site it is that you would rely on for doing your note taking.  There are other software that give you a WYSIWYG LaTeX formatting, such as LyX (which I have never used personally), if _that_ is what you're after.

Comment: Suggest asking at the Meta site instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: Please note that math.stackexchange does not use latex, it uses MathJax which just emulates a subset of tex commands and does not use tex for rendering

Answer (score 2):

MathJax provides a javascript application that makes writing LaTeX similar to Math StackExchange.  https://www.mathjax.org/

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress supports LaTeX.  You could use their wordpress.com service to host it, or run your own wordpress site using one of the LaTeX plugins

https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/latex/

Comment: I published it on Wordpress https://wordpress.com/post/watermelonsmugglersanonymous.wordpress.com/43?set-editor=classic

I will try the plugin on my own site later.